# How do you define the ease-in and ease-out of css links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a basic layout and this is currently the css for my links

```
a:link {
color: #232323;}

a:visited {
color: #232323;}

a:hover {
letter-spacing: 1px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
cursor: pointer}

a:active {
text-decoration: none;}
```

This is probably a stupid question but I'm still practicing my html/css skills. What I wanna do with my links is that when you hover over them, I want them to smoothly space out hence the letter-spacing in a:hover. I've tested it and it works pretty good, my problem is that when you move your mouse off the links, they don't smoothly go back to original letter spacing. To better explain, when you hover over them, they space out by 1 px but when you hover off, they just snap back into 0px when I wan't them to *transition* into 0px.

I believe (I'm probably wrong) I can fix this with proper use of the ease-in and ease-out tags but I'm not sure how I can incorporate that into my css and I've looked everywhere but I can't find my answer so here I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you need to define the `transition` on the element *before* any action occurs on it, ie. in the `a` rule, not the `a:hover` rule.

There's also a couple of other things to note:

- You don't need the vendor prefixes on `transition`. That rule now has support in all major browsers.
- `cursor: pointer` isn't required in the `hover` state as it occurs by default.

Try this:

```css
a { 
  transition: letter-spacing 1s ease; 
}
a:link, 
a:visited {
  color: #232323;
}
a:hover {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have defined the transition on the `:hover` state of the element. You should define it on the element itself.

That way, the transition will be applied always, no matter what is the state of the element.

```
a {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

a:link {
    color: #232323;
}

a:visited {
    color: #232323;
}

a:hover {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: i wasn't aware you had to define the hover transition to a whole other element, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It snaps back because your links in default state have no transition.

Move your transition to a new rule for `a` itself:

```
a {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

This will extend all other states like `a:link` and `a:hover`.

Comment: wow i had no idea you even had to make a new rule like that, thank you!